# How to create Table of Contents in pdf as shown in the image, using jasper/jrxml?

Tags: java, pdf, jasper-reports, bookmarks

Sample image demonstrates the Table of contents in pdf using jasper reports

[image]

Providing a sample code will be a great help.

Answer (score 4):

Note this is answer is not about creating table of content but creating the bookmarks showed in image, hence question is interpreted as how can I create these bookmarks.

The bookmarks in pdf using jasper report is done using the following code

```
<textField bookmarkLevel="1">
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
            <textElement lineSpacing="Single"/>
            <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{FIELD_NAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
            <anchorNameExpression><![CDATA[$F{FIELD_NAME}]]></anchorNameExpression>
</textField>
```

Where the anchorNameExpression is the name of the bookmark and the bookmarkLevel is the level, if jasper report finds first level 1 and the level 2, all level 2 will be grouped under level 1 until level 1 is not detected again.

If you are using ireport right click, choose hyperlink and set your values.